# node.js v18, only import works but export doesn't

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am using node.js v18.17.0
I have set in package.json that `"type": "module"`

I use `import http from 'http'` which doesn't give me any error
However, if I try to use export like:

```
function renderStatus(url){
    var arr = ["/home", "/list"]
    return arr.includes(url)?200:404

}

export renderStatus
```

It gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you can use ```export {renderStatus}``` and see where it goes

Comment: How do you import the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Being Shame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7325247/being-shame) said, `export {renderStatus}` should be the correct syntax.
We can also `export function renderStatus(url){...}` to export a function.

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 1):

Use Can Fix It By Either Of These;

1. use `export default renderStatus` (if this is the only export from the concerning file)
2. use `export { renderStatus, export2, export3....}` (in case of multiple exports from the concerning file)